# How to create DRY CSS when using transform & keyframes

Tags: css, keyframe

I'm trying to achieve [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) CSS code when using `transform` in combination with `keyframes`. Let's say I've got the following:

**HTML**

```
<div id="box"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#box {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:red;

    animation: animate 5s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes animate {
    from {
        transform: scale(0.8) translateY(100px) rotate(10deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(0.8) translateY(100px) rotate(-10deg);
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/gmn3L/).

How can I prevent doing the `scale(0.8)` and `translateY(100px)` inside the animation? I only want it to be rotated back and forth, without having to apply these properties inside transform for each step. Here, only two steps are used (`from` and `to`), but if multiple steps are used (for example with `0%`, `20%`, `40%`, `60%`, `80%`, `100%`) it would mean a lot of repeated code. As you can imagine, this isn't very good when changes will appear later.

Ultimately, I'm looking for something like this (which isn't possible, since the `transform` property will get overridden):

```
#box {
    transform: scale(0.8) translateY(100px);
}

@keyframes animate {
    from {
        transform: rotate(10deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(-10deg);
    }
}
```

Is this even possible?

Ps. I'm not looking for an answer where you would change the `width`/`height` to `scale` and/or change the `margin`/`top` property to `translate`. Also nothing with LESS/SASS to make the values easy to change, since it would still result in duplicated code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I put together two options for you- [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/gmn3L/9/)

**Option 1**- Not DRY but a little more condensed:

```
 #box {
        width:300px;
        height:300px;
        background:red;
        animation: animate 1s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;
    }
    @keyframes animate {
        from {
            transform: scale(0.8) translateY(100px) rotate(10deg);
        }
        to {
            transform: scale(0.8) translateY(100px) rotate(-10deg);
        }
    }
```

**Option 2**- Technically DRY, but not necessarily "better"

```
<div id="option2">
    <div id="box2"></div>
</div>

#option2{
    transform: scale(0.8) translateY(100px);
}
#box2 {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:blue;
    animation: animate2 6s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes animate2 {
    0%, 40%, 80% {
        transform: rotate(10deg);
    }
    20%, 60%, 100% {
        transform: rotate(-10deg);
    }
}
```

I would guess that using Option 2 may be worth it, if you're using a much more complex animation, but I'm not sure if just wrapping it in a containing `div` and scaling / translating the containing `div` would offer any real benefit on a small scale.

Comment: Although I'm not 100% satisfied with the solution, I do now understand that a proper solution simply isn't possible. Yet, your second option is better in my case, since no copy-pasting is needed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MarcoK Thanks, honestly this was the first time I've seen the DRY concept. I'll likely be using it on my site for a few heavily repeated styles.

Answer (score 0):

Wow so I thought that there surely had to be a way to do this without having to re-write the scale and translateY properties for every keyframe animation.  I tried several different things but I wasn't able to get the results you wanted.  It almost seems as though transform should be able to take on more parameters without overwriting the old ones if the parameters are new.

I know you said you don't want to use LESS/SASS as it isn't technically DRY but if you are looking to code in one place and have it update everywhere I would recommend that.  I would consider it DRY since you aren't repeating yourself (even though the code is).  I can't think of any other way to get what you want.

Comment: First, thank you for your effort. Sad to hear that you're actually bumping to the same conclusion as me, but I still hope there's some better way to do it.